# Algorithm problem

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, algorithm, visual-studio-2008

I have divided the circle into rows and columns and each block(square) formed in the circle is of equal size. I have the X and Y co-ordinates of each square/block. Each block is either defined as good or bad.

Problem: I need to add 2 blocks on the same row and determine if the result is good or bad. If any of the block is bad, the group of two block is called as bad. If both are good, only then group is good. what would be the algorithm for it? I need to do in visual basic language.  Also, I need to do more cases like adding 3 blocks and determine if the group of 3 block is good or bad. In this, if any block is bad, the whole group is bad.

Update: When I divided the circle into rows and columns i.e blocks, I remove the blocks that are not in the shape of square. That is, those square/blocks which are touching the circumference of circle are deleted. I can upload the photo tomorrow now.

Comment: Comment: 1) Please state what it means good/bad (manual input?) 2) for better responses, try to draw a picture of what you have now, and what you need later.

Comment: I tried to put the photo here but my score was not enough here and it didnot let me to upload the pic here. My score is 10 now.

Comment: Yes, good/bad are the inputs. I tested the blocks and some blocks are working and other's not. So, I give them this name-good/bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding two, then one badBlock means both on either side are also bad leading to 3 bad on

1) Set up NxN array of struct {bool inCircle, badBlock, badGroup;}
Where inCircle is true if the block is in the circle, badBlock is true if the block is a bad on and initially badGroup is false.

3)

```
int length=2;
length--;
for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
  for(int j=0; j<N;j++)
     if(array[i,j].badBlock){
       for(int x=-length;x<=length;x++)
           if(i+x>=0 and i+x<N and array[i+x,j].inCircle) then array[i+x,j].badGroup=true; 
       for(int y=-length;y<=length;y++)
           if(j+y>=0 and j+y<N and array[i,j+y].inCircle) then array[i,j+y].badGroup=true; 
}
```

Comment: Hey...This solution is god but I don't have to check for cloumn cases. Like,When I iterating a row, I only consider the blocks that are in the row. You can see the updated question here and help me in getting the right solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780456/algorithm-problem-with-the-picture-attached