# Algorithm problem- with the picture attached

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns

I am attaching a picture where I have shown the diagram for which I need to check the good/bad blocks. Basically, I have the information of size of each block and number of rows and column. I also know if the row has even or odd number of blocks.

I need to make a cluster of 2 blocks and check if the resultant block(with the combination of 2) is good or bad. If the 2 blocks are good, then the resultant is good block , otherwise bad.

I need to know the algorithm of it.

If the row has odd numbers of blocks, I am ignoring the middle block and considering the last blocks.

The diagram is in the shape of circle but the blocks on the circumference are ignored. So, I have to consider only the middle block as shown in the picture.

I need to iterate over each row, make a group of 2, find the result. But if the row has odd number of blocks, ignore the middle one, and make a group of last two blocks at the corner.

The shape inside the circle as shown in picture, is the real figure.

I guess, I have given enough information this time.

NOTE: In this example, I making a group of two, but I need to make a group of 2, 3 or 4 blocks in the row ,just like a generic case. If any block in the group is bad,the whole group is bad whether its a group of ,3, or 4.I need to write the code in visual basic language. The size, no. of blocks in the row shown in the picture are not the real data.It is just an example.

I have some type of solution that checks for each block and its surrounding block which is not right. But Can it be done in this way:

Here's solution:

If you are adding two, then one badBlock means both on either side are also bad leading to 3 bad on

1) Set up NxN array of struct {bool inCircle, badBlock, badGroup;} Where inCircle is true if the block is in the circle, badBlock is true if the block is a bad on and initially badGroup is false.

```
int length=2;
for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
  for(int j=0; j<N;j++)
     if(array[i,j].badBlock){
       for(int x=-length;x<=length;x++)
           if(i+x>=0 and i+x<N and array[i+x,j].inCircle) then array[i+x,j].badGroup=true; 
       for(int y=-length;y<=length;y++)
           if(j+y>=0 and j+y<N and array[i,j+y].inCircle) then array[i,j+y].badGroup=true; 
}
```

I also the know the x and Y co-ordinate of each block.

[image]

Comment: You just need an algorithm how to skip the middle block ? or do you need a full calculation ?  or something per row ?

Comment: We are going to need sample input and sample output to even begin to answer this.  I fear your question will be closed if you don't do this and maybe provide us with the code you have so far.

Comment: @yochai- I need to do the calculation also to find the good or bad block. Like, If I make a group of 2 or 3, if any block is bad , the whole group is bad.

Comment: @hoodaticus- please dont close the question. I made so much effort in writing and posting a picture. I will see if I can give you the data. I need your email id to send my file to you. OR you can just assume its size of block 2 units and make 3 rows of 8,9,7 no. of blocks respectively. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't have the power to close your question; I'm just trying to help.  They tend to close questions pretty quickly around here.  Let me see if I can make sense of this.  I'm upvoting your question because of the effort you've put in.

Comment: I am going to explain it in a new way. That would be better as it seems to be very hard to understand. I will change it and let you know here

Comment: I think we're only missing two pieces of information: 1) where does the circle come from?  and 2) What makes a block "bad".  Is it because part of it is not in the circle?  This question is getting fun, and you might end up with an answer based on Newtonian calculus.  Which is also fun.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6785082/revised-algorithm-problem-with-new-picture-and-information

Comment: Please see the above link in the comment

Answer (score 0):

simple recursion will do, pseudo-code:

```
GroupSize = 2;
bool Calc(row, start, end)
{
   if (end-start <= GroupSize -1) return true;
   if (end - start < GroupSize*2) //Single group in the middle, but smaller than 2 groups (calculate only the first group size)
   {
      bool result = true;
      for (i = start ; i < GroupSize; i++)
      {
         result = result && row[i];
      }
   } 
   else
   {
       return Calc(row, start, start + GroupSize) && Calc(row,end-GroupSize,end) && GroupSize(row, start + GroupSize,end-GroupSize);

   }
}
```

Something like that.
The idea is to recursively calculate both sides of the row and then send the middle for some more calculating.

Recursion might be simplest way (or not for everyone), bu any recursion can be turned into a loop.

Comment: I know the X and Y coordinate of each block and its information like if it is bad or good. In the Excel sheet, I have these 3(c,y,b/g) parameters.

Comment: What excel sheet? didn't you ask something about calculating groups of information in a row ?

Comment: Please see the updated part in the question, I added a solution, which is not right, but can of similar type.

Comment: Yes, in the excel sheet, I have the information of x and Y co-ordinate of each block and its information if the block is good or bad. But I need to find the result of group of  2 or 3 blocks whether they form a good or bad group.

Comment: In the solution provided by me, doesnot check the middle block. Also,I am concerned only for the row. I dont want to keep the column blocks also. Just do calculation for row by row.

Comment: user847323: You can do a simple loop to find the boundaries of the row (loop from the beginning till you find someone in bounds, and loop from the end to find the last)